# How to find an Element by index in selenium Webdriver for python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[This is HTML code of that page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRiod.jpg)

From there I want to access the 2nd element by using class name "maxbutton-1" as it has 3 same buttons and I can't use xpath or any constant selector so want to use the indexing with class and can't find anything to do that in python particular.

Also tried the method used in java to do same thing but it didn't worked.

[Link of that same page](https://moviesverse.org/download-iron-man-2008-hindi-tamil-480p-720p-1080p/)

just trying to automate the movie downloading process for any movie.

Thank you.

Comment: Show your code trials and errors. Do not add the screenshot of the code that can be simply pasted as code. which will be easy to debug the things.

Comment: so, what is your question?find element or help you download links?or download movies automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on first, second or third button, try to change number of element:

```
el1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[@class='maxbutton-1 maxbutton maxbutton-download-links'])[1]")

el2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[@class='maxbutton-1 maxbutton maxbutton-download-links'])[2]")

el3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[@class='maxbutton-1 maxbutton maxbutton-download-links'])[3]")
```

then you can extract element href/link attribute like that:

```
link = el.get_attribute('href')
```

or click it like that:

```
el.click()
```